# android: How to use custom colors?

Tags: android, background-color, android-framelayout

Im trying to set the backgroundcolor of my `FrameLayout` using my own colors.

I created a `.xml` file which contains my own colors.
Here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<resources>
    <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
    <color name="orange">#FF7D00</color>
    <color name="yellow">#FFFF00</color>
    <color name="green">#00FF00</color>
    <color name="blue">#00B4FF</color>
    <color name="black">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

And here is the code where Im trying to set the backgroundcolor, but when I run the app, the `FrameLayout` is always grey, why?:

```
FrameLayout MyFrameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
LayoutParams MyFrameLayoutParam = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 200);
MyFrameLayout.setLayoutParams(MyFrameLayoutParam);

MyFrameLayout.setBackgroundColor(R.color.red);

Parent.addView(MyFrameLayout);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to retrieve the color from resources before setting it.  You are assigning the R.java id not the actual value.

```
Color red = getApplicationContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.red)
MyFrameLayout.setBackgroundColor(red);
```

Comment: I think it's R.color.red instead of R.id.red

Answer (score 3):

To use your custom colour in xml, you would use something like:

`android:color="@color/orange"`

Answer (score 3):

This makes a button background green, find the color hex you want.

yourButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#25b72f"));

Answer (score 1):

You can use setBackgroundResource(Color)

Here an example:

`relativelayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green);`